# Error in proj4js-Projection while upgrading from OpenLayers 5 to OpenLayers 6 (ETRS:25832 projection)?

Tags: proj4js, openlayers

I have a map with some layers in Projection **EPSG:25832**. This works well with **OpenLayers 5.3.3**. But when I change to **OpenLayers 6.4.3** (or all others down to 6.0.1) then there is an error in the Definition of my projection. I am using proj4js in the version 2.6.2 (also tried older versions).

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.2/proj4.js

Error thrown from Proj4js:
`Uncaught TypeError: coordinates must be finite numbers .... proj4-2.6.2.js:1:4846`

Sourcecode in **Openlayers-5** and **Openlayers-6**

```
var oBoundsGesamt = [ 456700,5200500,773480,5835251 ];

proj4.defs(sEpsgNummer, "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs ");
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

var oOlProjection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:25832');
oOlProjection.setExtent( oBoundsGesamt  );

var oMapObj = new ol.Map({
   target: 'ebMapObj',
   layers: [ ... ], 
   view: new ol.View({
        projection : oOlProjection,
        extent: oBoundsGesamt,
```

Can somebody help me with this? The error is thrown at the end when I try to zoom to an Extent:

- `ol.control.ZoomToExtent({ extent: oBoundsGesamt })` or
- `oMapObj.getView().fit(oBoundsStart, oMapObj.getSize());`

Comment: proj4 will only be used if one of your layers uses a different projection.  It would be useful to see more of your code and the full call stack for the error.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - at the beginning I tried without proj4 but as this didn't help, i included this. I will try without and then update the question with more source code.

Comment: Thanks. It seemed to be a problem with the **extent in my ol.View** ... When I remove the proj4 lib/projection and reduce the Projection to `var oOlProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({ code: sEpsgNummer, units: 'm' });` then the map is white but no errors any more with Openlayers 6. When I scroll in after two steps the maps appears :-)

Comment: Now i have removed the **extent** from every layer and added it only to the definition of the Projection (`var oOlProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({ code: sEpsgNummer, units: 'm', extent: oBoundsEtrs25832Ganz });` ). 
After that the map shows up. The ol.View only has a **projection, center, zoom** level. It seems that the extent/Bounds were to small because OpenLayers startet with this extent but as the map asks for more (default: 1.0 ratio) the extent might have been to small and therefore the white map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Mike for helping me to get off the wrong track. Now it works fine with OpenLayers 6

The problem in my case was that I could remove the proj4 library which made life easier. I started with the OSM Example Map with EPSG:3587 and added my own WMS Server with EPSG:25832. Therefore I initially neeeded a reprojection. But as all my layers in my final result are in EPSG:25832 I could remove the proj4 without any need for reprojection.

Then there was only the problem left, that the map was white and didn't show anything on start - but when I zoomed in the map appeared. This was resolved by changing the zoom level of the ol.View and removing the extent from the ol.view (now only: projection zoom and center Attributes in the ol.View). After the experiences in my current map with OpenLayers 2 I couldn't imagine that a Map with layers could be build/constructed completely without an extent - only a center-Coordinate is needed.

Here the (reducced) source

```
var oBoundsEtrs25832Ganz = [ 265948.8191, 6421521.2254, 677786.3629, 7288831.7014 ]; //Bounds from: https://epsg.io 
var oOlProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({ code:'EPSG:25832', units: 'm', extent: oBoundsEtrs25832Ganz });
...
var sMapservUrlUndMapfileMs = 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/webapps/anwendungsname/dynamisch.map';
...
var oWmsSourceMapserverStrassen = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: sMapservUrlUndMapfileMs,
    params: {'LAYERS': 'openlayers_hintergrund', 'VERSION':'1.1.1' },
    serverType:  'mapserver'
});
var oLayerStrassennetz = new ol.layer.Image({ 
    source: oWmsSourceMapserverStrassen, 
    opacity: 0.6,
    zIndex: 2
}); 
...
var oMapObj = new ol.Map({
  target: 'ebMapObj',
  layers: [oLayerStrassennetz],
  view: new ol.View({
      projection : oOlProjection,
      center: [ 734565, 5306769 ],
      zoom: 6
  })
});
```